# Is there anything I can do legally when my daughter lets her boyfriend in our home without our permission?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, trespass

My daughter is 16, and my wife and I just found she's been sneaking her boyfriend (who is 17) into our house while we're not home. His parents don't seem to be doing anything about it.

Does this count as breaking and entering if my daughter, a minor, allows him into the house without our permission? Or is it trespassing? Or both?

Comment: Did you explicitly forbid _him_ to enter?

Comment: I have told them both that he's not allowed to be there when my wife and/or I am not there.

Comment: Question: Is there anything that you can do using the law that won't upset your daughter deeply and damage her relationship with you? Or are you just curious?

Comment: Great question. At this point, I'm curious. It's to the point that my wife is starting to feel uncomfortable in our own home. Should something unexpected happen, mostly I'd like to know what options are available.